# AutocompleteBox from Silverlight Toolkit does not work well with numbers

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, autocompletebox

I implemented a simple project to show you my problem. I have a simple web service that complete (french) cities by name or zip code. When I put a letter, the AutocompleteBox shows a list of cities as expected. If I put a number, it doesn't display the list, even though I traced the code, and it's populating and parsing well...

Is it a known issue ?

Download my sample project (just a default template with the autocompletebox) : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3475545/Autocomplete.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your service is doing the filtering you need add `FilterMode="None"` to the xaml on your `AutoCompleteBox`.  By default the mode is `StartsWith` so you service is fetching all the Cities with matching Zip codes but then AutoCompleteBox is excluding them all because none actually start with the Zip code.